# Mongodb faster execution for $in for array for millions of records

Tags: javascript, mongodb, join, mongodb-query, aggregate

I have two mongodb collections:
1). First collection is: `sourcequeuemanualupload` . It contains all records with statuses either Unworked or Assigned. This contains records when data is uploaded. Example of one of the Assigned item record in DB:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63e0e46a6047d75b9c20d8ec"),
    "Properties: Name" : "Hangman - Guess Words",
    "Appstore URL" : "https://itunes.apple.com/app/id1375993101?hl=None",
    "Region" : "na",
    "Create Date" : "na",
    "AHT" : "1",
    "sourceId" : "63e0e3719b4f812ba5333a31",
    "type" : "Manual",
    "uploadTime" : "2023-02-06T11:28:42.533+0000",
    "status" : "Assigned",
    "batchId" : "63e0e3719b4f812ba5333a31_746f22e4319b4d81b8ab255f5e653c2c_612023112842"
}
```

2). Second collection is `queuedata`. It contains the data(questions, responses user takes on tool) for items(from `sourcequeuemanualupload` collection) worked upon and they are all saved in this collection with a status of `Completed`. The _id of the record in `sourcequeuemanualupload` is stored here as "id" field as an identifier. Example of completed item:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63e0e4b19b4f812ba5333a34"),
    "templateId" : "63e0e28e9b4f812ba5333a30",
    "id" : "63e0e46a6047d75b9c20d8ec",
    "moderator" : "kodaga",
    "startTime" : "2023-02-06T11:29:46.048Z",
    "endTime" : "2023-02-06T11:29:52.438Z",
    "status" : "Completed",
    "AHT" : NumberLong(6),
    "userInput" : [
            {
                    "question" : "Is the URL leading to the desired store page link?",
                    "response" : "yes"
            },
            {
                    "question" : "Comments, if any.",
                    "response" : "test 1"
            }
    ]
}
```

There was a mistake made by the DBA initially as he did not update the status of Assigned items that were completed to `Completed` in `sourcequeuemanualupload` collection. So the Assigned items are left as Assigned itself. We are working on a fix for this to mark all the Assigned items(that have been worked upon) to Completed.

Volume of data currently:

```
> db.sourcequeuemanualupload.count()
414781
> db.sourcequeuemanualupload.count({"status":"Assigned"})
306418
> db.queuedata.count()
298128
```

Script I have written currently to identify the completed records and mark them as completed:

```
var assigned_tasks_arr = [];

db.sourcequeuemanualupload.find({ status: "Assigned" }).forEach(function (rec) {
  assigned_tasks_arr.push(rec._id.str);
});

print(assigned_tasks_arr.length)
> 306418

db.queuedata.count({ id: { $in: assigned_tasks_arr }, status: "Completed" }); // <------------- STEP 1

var completed_items = db.queuedata
  .find(
    { id: { $in: assigned_tasks_arr }, status: "Completed" },
    { _id: 0, id: 1 }
  )
  .toArray(); //    <------------- STEP 2

var completed_items_ids = [];

completed_items.forEach(function (rec) {
  completed_items_ids.push(rec.id);
});

var completed_items_unique_objectid = [];

completed_items.forEach(function (item) {
  completed_items_unique_objectid.push(new ObjectId(item));
});

db.sourcequeuemanualupload.updateMany(
  { _id: { $in: completed_items_unique_objectid } },
  { $set: { status: "Completed" } }
); // <------------- STEP 3
```

Basically, I fetch all the _ids of `Assigned` status items from `sourcequeuemanualupload` collection and store them in an array. Next to find if they actually have been completed and record is present in queuedata, I perform a search using $in and assigned_tasks_arr to get the actually completed items. Once i get the completed ids list, i would like to go ahead and update the statuses in sourcequeuemanualupload.

However, my STEP 1 and STEP 2 are taking>30 minutes for execution. It must be taking more than an hour or longer(but i could not get exact time as my session got terminated). I think the $in with array find query execution takes (N*log(M)), where N is the length of input array and M is the size of the collection. As you see my value of N is in millions and M is also in millions, this query will take a longer time. How do i optimize this query or write a faster query to find the ids and update at once?

**I need help with faster execution of STEP 1, STEP 2 and STEP 3 in above script so that I dont have to wait for hours. Can we write a better join query here or any other way to optimize the query?**

Thanks

I tried searching online for faster ways to optimize. I added index as 'id' to queuedata collection but it is still taking a long time :(
Need help for the above query

NOTE: using AWS documentDB 4.0.0 as if you are providing any suggestions on query , please check link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html as some commands are not supported

Comment: A few minutes of Googling didn't reveal the answer ... Does DocumentDB support updates with an aggregation pipeline?

Comment: @rickhg12hs thanks for the reply. I have not used aggregate before. This is AWS DOC: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html . Please could you help me out, im nearing deadline this week.

Comment: Is there a more detailed document that shows the syntax for each command?  For example, is there more detailed syntax documented for `update`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I am not finding it. The syntax in docdb is same as mongo just few operations not supported like $expr. Otherwise, syntaxwise its same only

Comment: @rickhg12hs i am connected to my documentdb mongo shell. If you want me to help with any command checking, let me know

Comment: I'm a javascript noob, but is there anything wrong with `db.queuedata.find({status: "Completed"}, {_id: 0, id: 1}).forEach((obj) => db.sourcequeuemanualupload.update({_id: new ObjectId(obj.id)}, {$set: {status: "Completed"}}))`?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the above query you shared. It is right. But will it run fast?

Comment: Only you can benchmark it on your system.

Comment: One small correction: `db.queuedata.find({status: "Completed"}, {_id: 0, id: 1}).forEach(function(obj) { db.sourcequeuemanualupload.update({_id: new ObjectId(obj.id)}, {$set: {status: "Completed"}})))`

Comment: Let me know if it's functional and performant.

Comment: @rickhg12hs let me try and get back

Comment: An index with key `{"status": 1}` for the `queuedata` collection may help, as well.

Comment: The script you asked me to try is executing. I will let you know once that is complete with the time it took (currently it would be for 298128 records). Currently, index is "id" in queuedata. Once this is done, i will add index for status and let you know. Should i add just `status:1` or `{"status": 1,"id":1}` for index?

Comment: Good question.  In MongoDB you could add both indexes and the query planner should pick the best one.  Hopefully DocumentDB does the same.

Comment: @rickhg12hs the script execution is completed. It took 15 minutes for 2.9 million records currently. We might excevute this in production in 2 weeks. Meanwhile, the size may increase till then by another 2 millions. Can we use something faster? Thanks for your help

Comment: @rickhg12hs till you reply, i will add index you suggested and check

Comment: @rickhg12hs I will be away for an hour as i have some house chores, in case i don't reply fast to any of your queries while helping me.

Comment: I'll be away for several hours, but others may help, as well.

Comment: @rickhg12hs your script works fine and marks them as completed in `queuedata`. But the execution time for 297776 records is 15 minutes. It is same with adding the appropriate indexes. Is there any other script where we can run this faster as currently it is way less than 1 million. Waiting for your input. thanks!

Comment: @rickhg12hs anything using other query ops like aggergate etc? I am not good with mongodb queries and would appreciate help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try it like this:

```
var completed_ids = []
db.sourcequeuemanualupload.aggregate([
   { $match: { status: "Assigned" } },
   {
      $lookup: {
         from: "queuedata",
         let: { id: "$_id" },
         pipeline: [
            { $mach: { status: "Completed" } },
            { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$$id", { $toObjectId: "$id" }] } } }
         ],
         as: "queuedata"
      }
   },
   { $match: { queuedata: { $ne: [] } } },
   { $project: { _id: 1 } }
]).forEach(rec => {
   completed_ids.push(rec._id);
   if (completed_ids.length > 10000) {
      db.sourcequeuemanualupload.updateMany(
         { _id: { $in: completed_ids } },
         { $set: { status: "Completed" } }
      );
      completed_ids = [];
   }
})
if (completed_ids.length > 0) {
   db.sourcequeuemanualupload.updateMany(
      { _id: { $in: completed_ids } },
      { $set: { status: "Completed" } }
   );
}
```

MongoDB version 4.0 is [End of Life](https://www.mongodb.com/support-policy/lifecycles), you may look for a modern MongoDB hosting service.

Another very simple approach would be this one:

```
db.queuedata.aggregate([
   { $match: { status: "Completed" } },
   {
      $project: {
         _id: { $toObjectId: "$id" },
         status: 1
      }
   },
   {
      $merge: {
         into: "sourcequeuemanualupload",
         whenMatched: "merge",
         whenNotMatched: "discard"
      }
   }
])
```

But this will update all documents in `sourcequeuemanualupload`, no matter if `status: 'Assigned'` or not.

A solution would be this one:

```
var completed_ids = [];
db.queuedata.aggregate([
   { $match: { status: "Completed" } },
   { $project: { _id: { $toObjectId: "$id" } } }
]).forEach(rec => {
   completed_ids.push(rec._id);
   if (completed_ids.length > 10000) {
      db.sourcequeuemanualupload.updateMany(
         {
            _id: { $in: completed_ids },
            status: "Assigned"
         },
         { $set: { status: "Completed" } }
      );
      completed_ids = [];
   }
})
if (completed_ids.length > 0) {
   db.sourcequeuemanualupload.updateMany(
      {
         _id: { $in: completed_ids },
         status: "Assigned"
      },
      { $set: { status: "Completed" } }
   );
}
```

When you going to fix your data, then `id` should be converted to `ObjectId` rather than a plain string.

Comment: Thanks a ton!! The third script that you suggested looks promising. I need to try this out. will let you know once done.

Comment: hi @wernfried , documentdb doesn't support $toObjectId

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html

Comment: I did some changes to your solution 3 and am using it. Updating 3 lakh records with your method takes just 3 minutes. Thanks for all the help.